# Boot fails, how to change grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I changed something in the grub file and ever since cannot boot anymore, so I think I inserted an error. I would like to restore it to default. How can this be done?

I booted ubuntu from USB and reinstalled grub, but this did not help.

I booted ubuntu from USB and made changes to the grub file, then ran sudo update-grub, but it returned `error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'`, so I suspect I cannot fix the grub file by booting from USB.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can fix it (probably) from a live session but you've to `chroot` in the installed system, otherwise you'll be working on the live session's Grub that cannot be changed (read-only).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have no experience with that, is it also possible with the grub terminal instead? I cannot boot, but I do get into the grub terminal.

Comment: chroot is not that difficult. This guide covers the steps. https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/chroot-to-repair-system  I’ve done this on Arch where I didn’t need all the extra mounts beyond / and /boot but it’s not too difficult it just appears difficult if you have not done it before

Comment: I got stuck with the chroot, I mounted all I need and then when trying sudo chroot /mnt it says permission denied, even though nothing in /mnt has noexec or nosuid option.

Comment: did you mount the device as root? probably not

Comment: I mounted it as root.

Comment: Did you change something in /etc/default/grub?

Comment: @nobody Yes, I changed the GRUB_DEFAULT from 0 to 2, because I wanted to load a different kernel. I checked the kernel list before and on 2, there was an earlier kernel as desired. However, after the change I could not boot anymore.

Answer (score 0):

okay note this is my special way. Boot up a live linux mount the filesystem, where

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

from your installed ubuntu is.
search in this file for block

```
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set default="2"
```

and change the part

```
set default="2"
```

to `set default="0"`
Try to boot your installed ubuntu. Make there the change in `/etc/default/grub` back to default and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

so the grub.cfg is regenerated.
for boot up a specific kernel.

Add in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

And again

```
sudo update-grub
```

boot up the kernel your want to start as default, and grub will remember this.